# Why is this structure impossible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, molecular-structure

I'm asked the following:

> Explain why the structure $\ce{H-C=C-H}$ doesn't make sense chemically.

Not only am I just looking for a check up of my answer, but am I making any sense in what I'm saying here? Am I mixing up or misunderstanding concepts here?

My answer was:

The hydrogen and carbon atom form a covalent bond. Hydrogen has only 1 electron in its valence shell, so it 'needs' 1 of carbon's electrons to complete it. Now there are 3 electrons left to take in the carbon atom. But this isn't enough to make a double bond with the other carbon atom: we're one electron short.

Does this sound about right?

Comment: There are three electrons left on *each* carbon. Your assumption will lead you astray.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this? Does a single bond in a structure have a 'higher priority' than a double bond?

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with "priority" it is about the the total number of electrons in play for bonding.

Comment: But the 3 electronscin the carbons are there because the hydrogens take one of each, right?

Comment: @Aperion We are just counting the total electrons available for bonding. The order you count them in doesn't matter so you are free to deal with  simpler bonds first and then see what is available for the rest. But you have to count the total correctly or you will not get a sensible answer.

Comment: OK, got it. Cheers! If you make an answer of it, I can accept it as such

Comment: @Apeiron You can also always write up a self-answer. That is encouraged on Stack Exchange ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis was a good start, but then it dropped. You need to consider four electrons on *each* carbon atom. *Each* of the two carbons can then form a single bond to one hydrogen atom using one of its electrons. *Each* of the carbon atoms then uses two of the remaining electrons to form the double bond.

Thus, *each* of the carbon atoms has one extraneous electrons; the structure would be a diradical structure. It should better be represented e.g. like this: $\ce{H-C^.=C^.-H}$.

It is possible for these two radicals to be alongside each other — see for example the structurally strongly related dioxygen molecule which is a triplet (diradical) in ground state and not adequately described in simple Lewis structure formalisms. However, it is highly unlikely for two carbons *without additional constraints* to form a diradical like that; forming a triple bond ($\ce{H-C#C-H}$) would be much better energetically (for carbon!).

Comment: Shine light on acetylene $\to$ get $\ce{H-C=C-H}$ $\to$ profit?

Comment: @orthocresol If only relaxation were not a thing ;P